# Python: while (True != True) loop

Tags: python, loops

I started learning to code this week so I'm playing around with small programs that I'm creating to try to get a better understanding of how it work.

One of the programs I made is a Pig Latin translator that loops until the user exits. The program works but the logic isn't making any sense to me.

```
pyg = "ay" #Pig Latin words end with ay.

def translate(): #Creating a function.
    original = input("Enter a word: ").lower() #Ask for input then convert to lower.
    if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha() : #isalpha() verifies only abc's and more than one letter.
        first = original[0] #Assigns the first letter of the string to first.
        latin = original[1:] + first + pyg #Adds original starting at 2nd letter with first and pyg.
        print(latin)
    else:
        print("You did not enter a valid word, please try again.")
        translate() #If you did not enter valid word, then call function again until you do.

translate() #Don't forget to actually call the function after you define it.

#Set run to False.
#Can be set to True if while (run != True) is set to while (run == True).
run = False

#Defining cont(). Ask for imput and error handling.
def cont():
    loop = input("Would you like to convert another word? (y/n): ").lower()
    if loop == "y" :
        run = True
    elif loop == "n" :
        run = False
        print("Thank you for using this program, have a nice day!")
        exit()
    else :
        print("You did not enter a valid response, please try again.")
        cont()

cont()

#Infinite loop as long as run is not equal to True.
while (run != True) :
    translate()
    cont()
```

My question is, why does this program work? I set run to False and I set the loop to run as long as run != True. No problem there, however when I defined cont(), I set run to take on the value True if the user inputs "y". True != True should be False (if I understand correctly) and the loop should end, but instead it is working as I wanted it to.

Is this a coding mistake that I've made or am I just thinking about this the wrong way? Thank you in advance.

**Edit:** Thank you very much to everyone that answered. I hadn't learned about local and global variables yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on what others have already stated, `run` on these lines

```
if loop == "y" :
    run = True
elif loop == "n" :
    run = False
```

are not referring to the same `run` defined by

```
#Can be set to True if while (run != True) is set to while (run == True).
run = False
```

`run` in the `cont` function is a local variable to your function, not the globaly defined `run`.

There are a couple (at least) ways to fix this.  The preferred (imo) way to do it is have `cont` return a new value to be assigned to `run`.  That would look like

```
#Defining cont(). Ask for imput and error handling.
def cont(_run):
    loop = input("Would you like to convert another word? (y/n): ").lower()
    if loop == "y" :
        return _run
    elif loop == "n" :
        return not _run
    else :
        print("You did not enter a valid response, please try again.")
        return cont(_run)

...

#Infinite loop as long as run is not equal to True.
while (run != True) :
    translate()
    run = cont(run)
```

The other (less preferred) way would be to use the global `run` variable inside of your `cont` function.  This is achieved using the `global` keyword.

That would look like this:

```
#Defining cont(). Ask for imput and error handling.
def cont():
    global run
    loop = input("Would you like to convert another word? (y/n): ").lower()
    if loop == "y" :
        run = True
    elif loop == "n" :
        run = False
        print("Thank you for using this program, have a nice day!")
        exit()
    else :
        print("You did not enter a valid response, please try again.")
        cont()
```

** Couple side notes
In my first example I return `_run` when the value is `y` and `not _run` when the value is `n`.  This allows you to change you initial `run` value to be True, and change the `while` condition without having to change the `cont` function itself.

You don't need to actually change the `run` value at all if you use the global and the user enters `n` since you exit before the function returns.

You might be better off changing your `if` conditional checks to

```
if loop in ("yes", "y"):
if loop in ("no", "n"):
```

since lots of people don't read full instructions :)

Answer (score 1):

The `run` inside the `cont` function is a local variable. Changing its value has no effect on the global variable that the while loop refers to.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably because of the scope of your run variable; because you're not returning run from your cont function. I believe what your != True check sees is always going to be False outside of that function, though obviously you can successfully end the program within the function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `run` variable defined in `cont()` is not the same as the `run` variable defined in the global scope.  (If you aren't sure what I mean by that you might want to look at https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces.  Perhaps a better approach for your code would be to have `cont()` return `True` or `False`.  It is also more intuitive and readable to use `True` for when you want to continue.  Here's how I would rewrite it.

```
pyg = "ay" #Pig Latin words end with ay.

def translate(): #Creating a function.
    original = input("Enter a word: ").lower() #Ask for input then convert to lower.
    if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha() : #isalpha() verifies only abc's and more than one letter.
        first = original[0] #Assigns the first letter of the string to first.
        latin = original[1:] + first + pyg #Adds original starting at 2nd letter with first and pyg.
        print(latin)
    else:
        print("You did not enter a valid word, please try again.")
        translate() #If you did not enter valid word, then call function again until you do.

#Defining cont(). Ask for imput and error handling.
def cont():
    while True:
        loop = input("Would you like to convert another word? (y/n): ").lower()
        if loop == "y":
            return True
        elif loop == "n": 
            print("Thank you for using this program, have a nice day!")
            return False
        else :
            print("You did not enter a valid response, please try again.")

translate()
while cont():
    translate()
```